# openpyxl - how to print rows that contain cell with specific value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm developing an automation for the office that I work that consists of finding lines with specific values ​​in a certain column and print the rest of values in that row to put in a e-mail.
I'm even able to print but it only returns the data of the last line that contains the word 'SIMPLE' and not all.

Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/fechamento.xlsx')
sheet = wb['fechamento']

lastCol = sheet.max_column

integrantes = {}
codigos = []
nomes = []
cnpjs = []
emails = []
tributacoes = []

for r in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for c in range(1, lastCol + 1):
        codigo = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        nome = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        cnpj = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=4).value
        tributacao = sheet.cell(row=r, column=5).value
        codigos.append(codigo)
        nomes.append(nome)
        cnpjs.append(cnpj)
        emails.append(email)
        tributacoes.append(tributacao)
        integrantes[nome] = email
        
trib = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
if trib != 'SIMPLES':

    print('Line:', r, 'Column:', c, '|', 'Código:', codigo, '|', 'Razão Social:', nome, '|', 'CNPJ:', cnpj, '|', 'E-mail:', email, '|', 'Tributação:', tributacao, '|')
```

Spreadsheet template used: https://prnt.sc/26or61m

Comment: The condition isn't within the the loop so can only ever work with the last row.

Comment: @CharlieClark How could I add a loop? Can you help me please?